# Почему при равном padding отличается поведение этих двух input?

Tags: html, css

[В этом коде](http://codepen.io/Andrew1024/pen/GNpMqO) в div test-name при добавлении padding-left: 4% input-ы перестают быть выровненными. При удалении этого padding-а они выравниваются.

```
<div class="test-name">
        <input class='test-name' placeholder="Test name" type="text">
        </br>
        <input placeholder="Description" type="text">
    </div>
```

Я хочу, чтобы первый input начинался там же где второй.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у description padding у вас и не добавляется. Вот так они будут на одном уровне [код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNgjvo)

html:

```
<div class="test-name">
    <input class='test-name' placeholder="Test name" type="text">
    </br>
    <input class="test-description" placeholder="Description" type="text">
</div>
```

css:

```
.test-name 
  padding-left: 4% // Здесь возможно что-то
  padding-right: 4%
.test-description
  padding-left: 4%
```